# Efficient way to regroup objects in array by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. These objects have two props: property 'label' of type String and a prop 'detections' which is an Array. I need a functions that can group the objects of same label merging the relative arrays.

For instance:

```
const list = [
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['a','b'] },
    { label: 'horse', detections: ['c','d'] },
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['e','f'] }
]
```

Would become:

```
const result = groupMergeByLabel(list)
// value logged would be => [
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['a','b','e','f'] },
    { label: 'horse', detections: ['c','d'] }
]
```

Comment: Does it have to be in an Array? Can the overall List be in an object?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const list = [
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['a','b'] },
    { label: 'horse', detections: ['c','d'] },
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['e','f'] }
];

const result = list.reduce((res, {label, detections}) => {
  const existing = res.find(x => x.label === label);
  if (existing) {
    existing.detections.push(...detections);
  } else {
    res.push({label, detections});
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hey, idk if it's okay to ask, do you have github?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the fastest method you can do that as [for loops are faster than map,reduce etc.](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4nvcd5/performancewise_is_the_for_loop_better_than_map/)

```js
const listA = [
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['a','b'] },
    { label: 'horse', detections: ['c','d'] },
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['e','f'] }
]

const groupMergeByLabel = (list) => {
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<list.length ;i++) {
      const index = res.findIndex(item => item.label === list[i].label);
    if(index > -1) {
      res[index].detections = [...res[index].detections, ...list[i].detections];
    } else {
      res.push(list[i]);
     
    }
  }
  return res;
};

console.log(groupMergeByLabel(listA))
```

Or you can use reduce as well,

```js
const listA = [
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['a','b'] },
    { label: 'horse', detections: ['c','d'] },
    { label: 'cat', detections: ['e','f'] }
]

const groupMergeByLabel = (list) => {
  const res = list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(item => item.label === curr.label);
    if(index> -1) {
      acc[index].detections = [...acc[index].detections, ...curr.detections];
    } else {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return res;
};

console.log(groupMergeByLabel(listA))
```